# Объединение запросов UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно объединить два sql update запроса в один

```
UPDATE test SET text = 'ok' WHERE id = '1'
UPDATE test SET text = 'no' WHERE id = '2'
```

Пробовал так:

```
UPDATE test SET text = 'ok' WHERE id = '1';
UPDATE test SET text = 'no' WHERE id = '2'
```

но не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: CASE попробуйте.

Comment: или union между запросами

Comment: union не работает

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE test SET text = 
CASE 
WHEN id = 1 THEN 'ok'
WHEN id = 2 THEN 'no'
ELSE text
END
```

Comment: Нехорошо'с: CASE уже был предложен

Comment: Ну ответе `UNION`'-ом.

Comment: @BuilderC, **ответа** с вариантом union не было предложено.  
Ответы- в ответы, все остальное в комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

```
update test join (select 1 a, 'ok' b union all select 2,'no') x
on test.id=x.a
set text=b;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно объединить два sql update запроса в один

Не нужно.
Не нужно объединять запросы без серьезной причины.
В данном случае ни одной причины нет - оба запроса прекрасно отработают по отдельности.

Если здесь нужна была *блокировка* строки, то, во-первых, её здесь нету, а  во-вторых, нет проблем сделать с блокировкой, двумя запросами.

Именно поэтому, задавая вопрос, надо всегда озвучивать реальную проблему, а не свои кустарные попытки её решить.